# openPrimaryTab() with lightning service cloud console in Spring '17

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, spring17

I have one lightning component which I have added in console

[openPrimaryTab()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_openprimarytab.htm) method is no longer working in new Lightning service console introduced in [Spring '17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_salesforce_console_for_service_lightning.htm)

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.SLDS104 + '/assets/js/integration.js'}" />
```

Sfdc.xdomain.Caller in integration.js (line 350) returns object while running in lightning console app it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Below line is working for me. Let me know.

```
<ltng:require scripts="/support/console/38.0/integration.js" />
```